# missing dependency for pcl_tutorials

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to rosmake pcl_tutorials and receive the following error:

tim@Linux-laptop-1:~/ros_workspace/pcl_tutorials$ rosmake --rosdep-install pcl_tutorials 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['pcl_tutorials']                                                                                         
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/tim/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110914-153143                                                         
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['pcl_tutorials'] to:
['pcl_tutorials']                                                                             
[ rosmake ] Generating Install Script using rosdep then executing. This may take a minute, you will be prompted for permissions. . .          
Failed to find rosdep libtiff for package pcl_tutorials on OS:ubuntu version:natty
[ rosmake ] rosdep install failed: Rosdep install failed                                                                                      
tim@Linux-laptop-1:~/ros_workspace/pcl_tutorials$

======

Any suggestions?

I did also tried to add/update the libtiff using Synaptic pkg manager but no difference.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11212/missing-dependency-for-pcl_tutorials/) by [Tim C](https://answers.ros.org/users/1028/tim-c/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-09-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you probably need `libtiff4-dev`, is that installed?

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1